# Prop passed to child component does not change its value in child upon updating prop in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have two functional components called Crucials and Timer, where Crucials is the parent and Timer is the Child.

Crucials has the user time data that needs to be passed down to the Timer for it to start the timer from the time provided by user.

My parent component is as follows:

```
export default function Crucials() {

const [Hdata, setHData] = useState(0);
const [Mdata, setMData] = useState(0);
let data = {
    Hour: 0,
    Min: 0,
    Sec: 0
};
function timerStart(){
    if(Hdata === 0 && Mdata === 0){
        console.log("Minimum Timer Initiated");
        setHData((minH)=> minH = 0);
        setMData((minM)=> minM = 15);
    }
    data.Hour = 0;
    data.Min = Mdata;
    data.Secy = Hdata; 
}


return (<div>
    <div><Timer timerdata={data}/></div>
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={timerStart}> Start Timer</Button>
    <form className={styles.HTM} onSubmit={timerStart}>
        <Input type="number" onChange={e => setHData(e.target.value) } id="outlined-basic" placeholder="Hours(H)" ></Input>
        <Input type="number" id="outlined-basic"  onChange={e => setMData(e.target.value)} placeholder="Minutes(M)" ></Input>
    </form>
</div>

)}
```

My child is as follows:

```
export default function Timer(timerdata) {

  let Seconds = timerdata.Sec;
  let Minutes = timerdata.Min;
  let Hours = timerdata.Hour;
....
...
}
```

All I want to do is for me to be able to pass the `data` object to the child and for it to only update when `timerStart` is invoked via the <kbd>Start Timer</kbd> button.

However, what is happening is that the data object passed to the child only ever holds the initialization values (0,0,0) and invoking `timerStart` function, which changes the values within data, is not reflected in the Child.

Also, for some odd reason, just inputting values into the two `<Input>` fields causes child to update data, but it still holds the initial values rather than what the user input.

I'm probably doing something wrong, but I'm unable to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `data` a state value, currently:

- your updates to your object won't persist between re-renders. Using `setHData`/`setMData` to update your state causes your component function to be called/executed again, redefining local variables such as the `data` object to the initial values
- updating your data alone using `data.Hour = 0;` etc. won't cause your component/children components to re-render with the updated values. As a result, you need to use react's state setter function, `setX` to signal to react that your `data` object has changed and that your component needs to re-render using the new state values.

Instead,  create a new state value that holds your `data` object, and use `setData()` to update it. This will cause your update to re-render your component + its children:

```js
const {useState} = React;
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({hour:1,min:2});
  const clickHandler = () => {
    setData({hour: 10, min: 20}); // use input values instead of hard-coding values
  };
  
  return <div>
    <Child data={data} />
    <button onClick={clickHandler}>Update data</button>
  </div>
}

const Child = (props) => <div>
  <p>H: {props.data.hour}</p>
  <p>M: {props.data.min}</p>
</div>;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Side note:**

Your code `setHData((minH)=> minH = 0);` can be written as `setHData(0);`, and same with `setMData(15)`. To update the state value, all you need to do is pass the new value to the state setter function. You don't need to pass an arrow function here, as your new value (0, and 15) doesn't rely on the previous state value.

Comment: It works! I removed the `HData` and `MData` states and replaced them with just the `data` state. Now it only updates when the button is pressed. This is the behaviour that I initially expected. I really appreciate you helping me out here. 

I have a couple questions though.

Comment: I would appreciate some clarification on this, however. 

**Using setHData/setMData to update your state causes your component function to be called/executed again, redefining local variables such as the data object to the initial values**

Is this a general characteristic of all states in a component? Do any of the states trigger re-render just upon being updated?

Comment: @BRSwift yeah, whenever you call a state setter function (such as `setData()` or `setHData()` etc.) _and_ the new state value you pass into the state setter function is different to the current value of your state, then your component (ie the `Crucials` function) + it's children components will re-render, which means that the `Crucials` function is gets called again (by React). You can see when your function/component renders/gets called if you add `console.log("rendering");`   at the very top of your `Crucials` function

Comment: I see, I guess that means I should be careful about the amount of states that I use in a parent component. I appreciate your help once again. Thank you!

Comment: @BRSwift The main consideration is about how many times you call your state setter functions, as that's what makes your function re-render. But it's fine to have multiple state values, as long as you're only calling the state setter functions for those state values when needed. If you feel as though this answers your question you can mark it as answered by clicking the grey checkmark in the top left corner of the answer :)